# Remove viewbox/container from svg

Tags: css, svg

I created a SVG using an SVG maker online but the SVG is always inside some container. I wanted to make this SVG my logo but since it is inside a container the letters inside the SVG are even more smaller and barely readable in logo size in the navbar.

Is it a good idea to put a SVG as a navbar logo or should I just stick to using an image?

I wanted to know if there is a way to remove the outer container of the SVG so that the text inside the SVG is redable

```html
<svg data-v-fde0c5aa="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300" class="iconLeft"><!----><defs data-v-fde0c5aa=""><!----></defs><rect data-v-fde0c5aa="" fill="#F3E9F1" x="0" y="0" width="300px" height="300px" class="logo-background-square"></rect><defs data-v-fde0c5aa=""><!----></defs><g data-v-fde0c5aa="" id="58a4ebde-7597-4708-9f95-6095e894a106" fill="#261624" transform="matrix(3.0857118626290814,0,0,3.0857118626290814,115.21840983754241,125.76173326019327)"><path d="M9.46 12.67L7.96 12.67L5.46 8.67L2.45 8.67L2.45 12.67L1.15 12.67L1.15 3.04L5.68 3.04L5.68 3.04Q7.31 3.04 8.19 3.77L8.19 3.77L8.19 3.77Q9.08 4.50 9.08 5.80L9.08 5.80L9.08 5.80Q9.08 6.87 8.45 7.60L8.45 7.60L8.45 7.60Q7.83 8.33 6.73 8.52L6.73 8.52L9.46 12.67ZM7.77 5.81L7.77 5.81L7.77 5.81Q7.77 4.97 7.19 4.53L7.19 4.53L7.19 4.53Q6.62 4.09 5.55 4.09L5.55 4.09L2.45 4.09L2.45 7.64L5.61 7.64L5.61 7.64Q6.64 7.64 7.20 7.16L7.20 7.16L7.20 7.16Q7.77 6.68 7.77 5.81ZM18.85 12.67L11.26 12.67L11.26 3.04L18.57 3.04L18.57 4.11L12.56 4.11L12.56 7.20L18.16 7.20L18.16 8.25L12.56 8.25L12.56 11.61L18.85 11.61L18.85 12.67ZM27.68 4.11L24.37 4.11L24.37 12.67L23.07 12.67L23.07 4.11L19.76 4.11L19.76 3.04L27.68 3.04L27.68 4.11ZM36.74 12.67L29.15 12.67L29.15 3.04L36.46 3.04L36.46 4.11L30.45 4.11L30.45 7.20L36.05 7.20L36.05 8.25L30.45 8.25L30.45 11.61L36.74 11.61L36.74 12.67ZM42.75 3.96L42.75 3.96L42.75 3.96Q41.15 3.96 40.26 4.99L40.26 4.99L40.26 4.99Q39.38 6.02 39.38 7.81L39.38 7.81L39.38 7.81Q39.38 9.58 40.30 10.66L40.30 10.66L40.30 10.66Q41.23 11.74 42.81 11.74L42.81 11.74L42.81 11.74Q44.83 11.74 45.85 9.73L45.85 9.73L46.92 10.27L46.92 10.27Q46.32 11.51 45.24 12.16L45.24 12.16L45.24 12.16Q44.17 12.81 42.75 12.81L42.75 12.81L42.75 12.81Q41.29 12.81 40.23 12.21L40.23 12.21L40.23 12.21Q39.16 11.60 38.61 10.48L38.61 10.48L38.61 10.48Q38.05 9.35 38.05 7.81L38.05 7.81L38.05 7.81Q38.05 5.51 39.29 4.20L39.29 4.20L39.29 4.20Q40.54 2.90 42.74 2.90L42.74 2.90L42.74 2.90Q44.28 2.90 45.31 3.50L45.31 3.50L45.31 3.50Q46.34 4.10 46.83 5.28L46.83 5.28L45.59 5.69L45.59 5.69Q45.25 4.85 44.51 4.41L44.51 4.41L44.51 4.41Q43.77 3.96 42.75 3.96Z"></path></g><defs data-v-fde0c5aa=""><linearGradient data-v-fde0c5aa="" gradientTransform="rotate(25)" id="a192775b-751f-4387-9a1b-18e0c0542f56" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%"><stop data-v-fde0c5aa="" offset="0%" stop-color="#E98C00" stop-opacity="1"></stop><stop data-v-fde0c5aa="" offset="100%" stop-color="#8F5BFE" stop-opacity="1"></stop></linearGradient></defs><g data-v-fde0c5aa="" id="7a764d3c-8d69-434e-ad0d-f46c440c5576" stroke="none" fill="url(#a192775b-751f-4387-9a1b-18e0c0542f56)" transform="matrix(1.3809339297847085,0,0,1.3809339297847085,38.60249606412651,115.72521765024868)"><path d="M19.937 10.508l-2.284-2.296-16.641 16.58 16.635 16.636 2.293-2.293L5.603 24.794zM29.714 10.508l14.332 14.286-14.335 14.341 2.293 2.293 16.633-16.636-16.636-16.58z"></path></g><!----></svg>
```

Comment: You need to remove the `rect` from the svg. so you need the size of the icon to be same?

Answer (score 0):

I have removed the container in the background:

```html
<svg data-v-fde0c5aa="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 300 300" class="iconLeft"><!----><defs data-v-fde0c5aa=""><!----></defs><defs data-v-fde0c5aa=""><!----></defs><g data-v-fde0c5aa="" id="58a4ebde-7597-4708-9f95-6095e894a106" fill="#261624" transform="matrix(3.0857118626290814,0,0,3.0857118626290814,115.21840983754241,125.76173326019327)">
<path d="M9.46 12.67L7.96 12.67L5.46 8.67L2.45 8.67L2.45 12.67L1.15 12.67L1.15 3.04L5.68 3.04L5.68 3.04Q7.31 3.04 8.19 3.77L8.19 3.77L8.19 3.77Q9.08 4.50 9.08 5.80L9.08 5.80L9.08 5.80Q9.08 6.87 8.45 7.60L8.45 7.60L8.45 7.60Q7.83 8.33 6.73 8.52L6.73 8.52L9.46 12.67ZM7.77 5.81L7.77 5.81L7.77 5.81Q7.77 4.97 7.19 4.53L7.19 4.53L7.19 4.53Q6.62 4.09 5.55 4.09L5.55 4.09L2.45 4.09L2.45 7.64L5.61 7.64L5.61 7.64Q6.64 7.64 7.20 7.16L7.20 7.16L7.20 7.16Q7.77 6.68 7.77 5.81ZM18.85 12.67L11.26 12.67L11.26 3.04L18.57 3.04L18.57 4.11L12.56 4.11L12.56 7.20L18.16 7.20L18.16 8.25L12.56 8.25L12.56 11.61L18.85 11.61L18.85 12.67ZM27.68 4.11L24.37 4.11L24.37 12.67L23.07 12.67L23.07 4.11L19.76 4.11L19.76 3.04L27.68 3.04L27.68 4.11ZM36.74 12.67L29.15 12.67L29.15 3.04L36.46 3.04L36.46 4.11L30.45 4.11L30.45 7.20L36.05 7.20L36.05 8.25L30.45 8.25L30.45 11.61L36.74 11.61L36.74 12.67ZM42.75 3.96L42.75 3.96L42.75 3.96Q41.15 3.96 40.26 4.99L40.26 4.99L40.26 4.99Q39.38 6.02 39.38 7.81L39.38 7.81L39.38 7.81Q39.38 9.58 40.30 10.66L40.30 10.66L40.30 10.66Q41.23 11.74 42.81 11.74L42.81 11.74L42.81 11.74Q44.83 11.74 45.85 9.73L45.85 9.73L46.92 10.27L46.92 10.27Q46.32 11.51 45.24 12.16L45.24 12.16L45.24 12.16Q44.17 12.81 42.75 12.81L42.75 12.81L42.75 12.81Q41.29 12.81 40.23 12.21L40.23 12.21L40.23 12.21Q39.16 11.60 38.61 10.48L38.61 10.48L38.61 10.48Q38.05 9.35 38.05 7.81L38.05 7.81L38.05 7.81Q38.05 5.51 39.29 4.20L39.29 4.20L39.29 4.20Q40.54 2.90 42.74 2.90L42.74 2.90L42.74 2.90Q44.28 2.90 45.31 3.50L45.31 3.50L45.31 3.50Q46.34 4.10 46.83 5.28L46.83 5.28L45.59 5.69L45.59 5.69Q45.25 4.85 44.51 4.41L44.51 4.41L44.51 4.41Q43.77 3.96 42.75 3.96Z"></path>
</g><defs data-v-fde0c5aa=""><linearGradient data-v-fde0c5aa="" gradientTransform="rotate(25)" id="a192775b-751f-4387-9a1b-18e0c0542f56" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%"><stop data-v-fde0c5aa="" offset="0%" stop-color="#E98C00" stop-opacity="1"></stop><stop data-v-fde0c5aa="" offset="100%" stop-color="#8F5BFE" stop-opacity="1"></stop></linearGradient></defs><g data-v-fde0c5aa="" id="7a764d3c-8d69-434e-ad0d-f46c440c5576" stroke="none" fill="url(#a192775b-751f-4387-9a1b-18e0c0542f56)" transform="matrix(1.3809339297847085,0,0,1.3809339297847085,38.60249606412651,115.72521765024868)">
<path d="M19.937 10.508l-2.284-2.296-16.641 16.58 16.635 16.636 2.293-2.293L5.603 24.794zM29.714 10.508l14.332 14.286-14.335 14.341 2.293 2.293 16.633-16.636-16.636-16.58z"></path></g><!----></svg>
```